# How to add listener to interpolated Animated value react native?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I want to add a listener to an interpolated Animated value, but the callback isn't being called at all...

My code is below, am I doing something wrong?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Animated } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const y = new Animated.Value(0);
  const yInt = y.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-100, 100],
    outputRange: [0, 10],
  });
  yInt.addListener(({value}) => console.log('yInt', value))

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(y, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, []);

  return <View />;
};
```